# Why did the output of "hostname -I" change when using the same PC?

Tags: android, ip

I'm creating an android app that connects to a local node.js server using socket.io.

I use `hostname -I`, `ifconfig`, and `ip addr show` to find my computer's IP address.

I did these commands earlier today and I saw that my IP address was 192.168.1.xx. I created a socket and was able to successfully connect my android app to my local server.

Now a few hours later, I test the android app and it no longer connects. I ran the commands again (snapshots below) and the output of the three commands i used to find my ip address are now different... the output points towards my IP address being 172.21.37.xxx.

Can the output of the three above commands change? I'm using the same machine, I don't know if this is relevant but I tri-booted my PC (I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 18, and Mint 18). I did move location, I'm using my library's public wifi.

Any information, including links to understanding more about how these commands work, would be very appreciated. I can post more info on request. If I find any new information I'll update the post.

hostname -I:

[image]

ifconfig:

[image]

ip addr show:

[image]

And as always, thanks for reading!

Comment: Sure your PC can change IP addresses. You probably connected to a different AP that hands out a different range of address. It's completely up to the router what IP address it gives to your PC. Your PC doesn't get to decide these things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification, it's appreciated. @JeffreyBlattman is there a way to accept your comment as the answer and close the issue? Maybe this is cuz of my low point total but I don't see the up and down arrow and the check mark that i usually do.

Comment: Thanks just accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeffrey said this first ^

If you moved location, it’s possible that your computer connected to a different router hosting your library’s wifi network. By using multiple routers like this, you can appear to cover a large area and have clients only have to connect to one network. Your device then should connect to the nearest source of that main network.

My guess is that by moving, your computer connected to a different router and was assigned a new local IP. If you stay in the same area this may not happen.